# php rename(file) is making 2 copies. sometimes. why?

Tags: php

on my php server I have 3 folders (including the root)
/
/lists
/lists/archive

I have a file called /lists/make.php which generates a static html file using today's date as the filename like this: /lists/20160203.htm

but before it makes today's list, it first checks for yesterday's list. If found, it MOVES it using the rename() command to the /lists/archive folder. However, it's doing more than just moving to archive, it is also creating a copy in root but it only does this every other day. And it's not just an even/odd problem because that switched at the end of January. For example, here is my file structure now. (note: today is 2016-02-03)

/20160128.htm
/20160130.htm
/20160201.htm
/20160203.htm
/lists/20160203.htm
/lists/archive/20160128.htm
/lists/archive/20160129.htm
/lists/archive/20160130.htm
/lists/archive/20160131.htm
/lists/archive/20160201.htm
/lists/archive/20160202.htm

So there are 3 odd things happening here that I need help fixing:
(1) yesterday's list should be only in the archive, not also in root
(2) why is this only a problem every other day???
(3) why is today's list already in root when the archive script has not executed yet?
(4) will tomorrow's list be in root?

Here is relevant code in /lists/make.php

```
<?php
$filename = date('Ymd',strtotime('yesterday')).'.htm';
if( file_exists($filename) ){
    //email a copy to admin
    $message = file_get_contents($filename);
    mail($emailAdmin, $subject, $message, $headers));
    //move list to archive
    rename('../lists/'.$filename, '../lists/archives/'.$filename);
}

//start or overwrite today's list
$filename = date('Ymd').'.htm';
$fh = fopen($filename,'w');
fwrite($fh, 'stuff1, stuff2');
fwrite($fh, 'stuff3, stuff4');

?>
```

If the "../lists/" part of rename() seems redundant, I agree, but adding that halfway fixed my problem. Before, I was just doing rename($filename,'archives/'.$filename) and it was making copies every day. Now it just makes copies every other day. I'm so confused. help!

/lists/make.php is included in a few other files on my site so that it is executed several times per day. That is my hacked solution to triggering backups since I can't control chron events on my shared host. Most of the files that call make.php are also in the /lists/ folder but one of them is in root, and one other is buried 2 levels deep in subfolders of /lists/. I don't think that is relevant but this problem is a mystery to me.

Comment: First of all, are you sure that are copies? Have you check if the content is exactly the same? Then, even better use absolute filepath rather than relative.

Comment: Agreed, this is probably not what you think it is.

Comment: In addition: where, how and when the script is called/executed?

Comment: yes, I have opened up archive copies and they are all unique and contain data only from that day. the archive folder is fine. It's the root folder that confuses me

Comment: and the copies in root exactly match the copies in archive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `rename(__DIR__.'/'.$filename, __DIR__.'/archives/'.$filename)`.  `__DIR__` refers to the directory of the script you use it in.  If you're including the script from multiple places then the relative path to /lists will give you different results from different scripts.

If it's being called by different scripts on different days it could explain why it's inconsistent.  Today's having run already could possibly be that you haven't adjusted the timezone, and in your server's time it's already tomorrow.

Comment: I will try that but I don't expect it to help. rename() is supposed to use the path of the file executing it (ie make.php) not the file that included make.php... and even if you're right about directory path, I can't explain why this only happens every other day for the past 12 days

Comment: `__DIR__` is the directory of the file it's written in, so in this case it will be the directory of make.php.  The way you have it now is relative to the script being executed (i.e. the file that included make.php).  Whether that will fix everything I couldn't say without more information, but if you're including make.php from multiple scripts in multiple directories, it could just be failing to execute properly only when coming from certain directories

Comment: still broken. I made the change on 0203 and that day did process correctly but now, 2 days later, I have 0204 and 0205 in root folder. what kind of bug is this? Maybe there is no fix... and I just have to program my script to check for and delete lists from root. shame

Comment: Make sure you use `__DIR__.'/'.$filename` when creating today's list as well.  Otherwise if you run it from the root directory, it will create the file in the root directory.  Your filename doesn't include the path as written in your question, so it would create the current day's file in whatever directory the executed script is called from, not the directory of the make.php include.

Comment: hmm, yes I was only using `__DIR__` for rename, not for fopen. I have changed that now and we will see in a few more days if it's working.

Comment: looks like it is working now. Still a mystery (or an amazing coincidence) that the problem happened exactly every other day... but it's fixed now. thank you.